# WARN r.c.j.JedisFactory: Error while close redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisException: Could not return the broken resource to the pool

Tags: java, multithreading, jmeter, jedis

I get the following error

```
WARN r.c.j.JedisFactory: Error while close
redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisException: Could not return the broken resource to the pool
```

Please tell me how it can be fixed. Because I get this error regularly. I think that there is an additional need to wrap something in "try" and "catch". Or is there a problem in something else ? I will be glad to help.

The code looks like this.

```
import redis.clients.jedis.Jedis;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import redis.clients.jedis.Response;
import redis.clients.jedis.Transaction;
import redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool;
import redis.clients.jedis.JedisPoolConfig;
import redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult;

JedisPool jedisPool = (JedisPool) props.get('jedisPool');
Jedis jedis = jedisPool.getResource();
List<Object> execResult = null;

String GetIncrNumber;
int countTry = 0;

 while(execResult == null) {
            try{
                jedis.watch("Number");
                Transaction t = jedis.multi();
                Response<String> rs = t.incr("Number");
                execResult = t.exec();
                GetIncrNumber = rs.get();
                t.close();
                t = null;
                rs = null;
            } catch (Exception e){
                countTry++;
                sleep(50);
                if(countTry > 15){
                    log.error("\r\nSome error (countTry = " + countTry + ") GetIncrNumber: " + e.getMessage() + "\r\n");
                }
          }  

}


execResult.clear();
vars.put("GetIncrNumber_JM", GetIncrNumber.toString()); 

//log.info(GetIncrNumber)
  
jedisPool.returnResource(jedis);

execResult = null;
jedis = null;
jedisPool = null;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should call [JedisPool.returnBrokenResource()](https://www.javadoc.io/static/redis.clients/jedis/3.0.0/redis/clients/jedis/JedisPool.html#returnBrokenResource-redis.clients.jedis.Jedis-) somewhere in [finally](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html) block and catching more specific exception?

you can also consider using [Jedis.close()](https://www.javadoc.io/static/redis.clients/jedis/3.0.0/redis/clients/jedis/Jedis.html#close--) instead.

By the way, have you considered using [Redis Data Set Config](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-redis-data-set-an-introduction) instead of writing the custom code?

Comment: I considered it, but then, at high intensity, the system can take the same value from the redis to two different streams.